# On the uniform continuity of some functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ with $\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x}}=0$.

Question: Is it true that $f$ must be uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$ ?

Comment: $f$ only needs to be bounded ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$f(x)=\sin(x^2)$$ satisfies the hypotheses, but it is not uniformly continuous.